# Laravel Redirect Wrong Virtual Host

Tags: php, laravel, apache, virtualhost

I'm working on a server that have a virtual host for 3 systems:

192.168.0.10/system-a

192.168.0.10/system-b

192.168.0.10/system-c

When i access 192.168.0.10/system-a the laravel redirect to 192.168.0.10/login, what i expect, was redirect to 192.168.0.10/system-a/login.

Is this kind of problem about configurations of apache, or laravel routes/web.php? Below is how my web.php :

```
<?php
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DownloadFileController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Compras\Configuracoes\PurchaseRequestController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


Route::redirect('/', '/login');

Route::redirect('/index', '/index');




Auth::routes(['register' => false]);

Route::get('/index', [\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
```

Comment: A Virtual Host identifies a totally seperate domain! Its not like a subfolder. So address the 3 seperate site like they were  google.com and microsoft.com and stackoverflow.com

Comment: I have never configured a Laravel app to work on a subfolder, what happens if you define `APP_URL` to be `http://192.168.0.10/system-a/` (or remove the ending `/`), does it change anything?

Comment: hi, if i interpreted you query  right you need three different installation for it inside your main folder ... then for each system you can do like. ```192.168.0.10/system-a/public``` ```192.168.0.10/system-b/public``` then you can configure 3 different domains/sub domains for it....... if thats not the case and you want to configure multiple domains for single install than you will have to modify routs/controller/middle ware for that